# Firestore finds undefined value in fully defined JSON, key does not even exist

Tags: node.js, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, undefined

I am trying to upload a JSON-object to Google Firestore.

When setting the Object to a Firestore Document my code throws the following Error:

```
Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. 
Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value 
(found in field audit.`20`.requests.`0`.lrEndTimeDeltaMs).
```

Now the first thing I did was log the Object right before the upload to check for undefined values:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(resultsToUpload));

return database
  .collection("foo1")
  .doc("bar1")
  .set(resultsToUpload);
```

Not only are all values defined in the object, but the mentioned field `` audit.`20`.requests.`0`.lrEndTimeDeltaMs `` does not even exist:

```
resultsToUpload = {  
  "audit":{   
    "20":{  
      "ronaldScore":3,
      "id":"network-requests",
      "requests":[  
        {  
          "url":"https://www.example.com/",
          "startTime":0,
          "endTime":62.16699999640696,
          "transferSize":15794,
          "resourceSize":78243,
          "statusCode":200,
          "mimeType":"text/html",
          "resourceType":"Document"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The data comes from a Google Lighthouse Audit.

Calculating the UTF-8 string length of the stringified JSON objects results in a size of 30 MB.

1) All values are defined (some are null, which should not be a problem).

2) The mentioned field does not even exist in the JSON.

My question is: How can this happen? How can a field just appear?
Also: How would I fix this issue?

Comment: Are you sure you're not writing somewhere else that could be causing the error. It seems very unlikely that Firestore would be throwing an error with a fairly domain-specific field name like that otherwise.

Comment: Hey Frank, what do you mean by "writing somewhere else"? The Code above is literally copy-pasted (apart from cropping the JSON), so I am logging the object right before the write.

Comment: So I checked the Code again, it is the only write Statement in the whole Code and the Error points exactly to ```.set(resultsToUpload);```

Comment: I just quickly copy/pasted the code into [this jsbin](https://jsbin.com/qidudeq/1/edit?html,js,console), where it runs without problems. You might want to try the same on your environment (so run it in complete isolation), as it seems **very** unlikely that Firebase will somehow make up the `lrEndTimeDeltaMs` if that isn't coming from your code.

Comment: I agree that that is rather unlikely. It looks like I made a mistake somewhere but I can not figure out what the actual issue is... I will try some stuff later. The jsbin you linked to seems to answer a different question, could you please check that? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry about that, this is the one: https://jsbin.com/qidudeq/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I figured it out! I was not aware that JSON.stringify hides "undefined"... So sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for your time!

Comment: Instead of adding the solution to your question you should post it as an actual answer. That way other people can more easely find it. There is nothing wrong with answering your own question :)

Comment: Thanks André, good to know!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using JSON.stringify on a Javascript-Object hides all "undefined" values (as well as their keys) and then stringifies what is left.

That is because JSON does not have such a thing as "undefined".

So the log showed a fully defined JSON, even though the actual JS-Object did contain "undefined" values.

Comment: I ended up here looking for something else but man this answer is a treasure.